# Angular 2 - Duplicated <style> blocks everywhere

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am using the latest Angular(4) with Angular CLI.  I followed the advice found on SO for setting up global scss that is available to components.

[Angular-CLI global scss vairables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781552/angular-cli-global-scss-vairables)

My structure looks like this

```
/
 styles.scss
 /styles
  variables.scss
  mixins.scss
  common.scss
 /app
  /component1
   component1.scss
  /component2
   component2.scss
```

The main styles.scss file has the following code

```
@import './styles/variables.scss';
@import './styles/mixins.scss';
@import './styles/common.scss';
```

And in my components, I start each component scss file with the statement of

```
@import '~styles.scss';
```

I thought that this was the correct way to bring global variables/mixins/common into my component's scss. However, when I started to have components within components, I began to notice that Webpack was actually creating one  block per component in the page, and each one of them had all of the global scss written out in them. So there would be one  block for component1, with ALL of the variables,mixins,common stuff at the top, and then another  block right below that one for the other component2 in the page, with all that information again.

Besides this being extremely inefficient, it means that the global styles are overwritting themselves (can see that in chrome debug) once for each time they are loaded. 
[image: Can see each one of the style blocks, they each start by writing out the global styles]

Some direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can disable `viewEncapsulation` in order to use global styles

Comment: Meaning what exactly? That I wouldn't have to @import the main styles.scss in my component styles? I have tried that and web pack fails to compile because it says that it doesn't know what certain scss variables are in the component scss files.

Comment: Just found out this seems to be an issue already being talked about. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1261  But if anyone has a clever solution, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you read the last comment you can find your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `<style>` tags are normal angular behaviour. Each components SCSS gets written into a `<style>` element, so there is nothing wrong with that. 
The style.scss is for global styles that do not need encapsulation. It also gets written into a `<style>` element, if you imported it in your angular.json:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css"
],
```

What you are getting wrong is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39781552/9277073) you linked (which is still not accepted).
You shouldn't import your already imported styles.scss (apart from variables or mixins) into your components, because this will lead to increasing bundle sizes, as you import the code over and over (which is also the reason for the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1261) you mentioned).

You can use the mixins, variables and common.scss simply by including them directly in your components SCSS, just as you need them.

Answer (score -2):

This is basic sass behaviour, you should never import things that result in css several times (sass files imported into component should typically only contain variables, mixins and functions). If you need your import to happen only once, add it to the default styles file. 
[Look here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8431)